# ZXing imports disappearing

Tags: android, android-studio, zxing

I am trying to install zxing in android studio but i am running into some trouble. I have looked around at lots of different posts and tutorials and they have all said to just add the following lines into the build.gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.1.0'
compile 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.1.0'
```

I have done this and synced everything but when I try and add an import like

```
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;
```

at the top of my project it instantly disappears without an errors or warning.

Has anyone else had this problem or know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IDE will remove the import if you have some auto-cleaning unused import statements. It depends on the IDE to configure this option but both Android Studio and Eclipse have this feature.

I suggest you to start using this `IntentResult` and then it will keep the import statement.

Comment: thanks for the reply, im pretty new to this so would you mind explaining what IntentResult is and how to use it?

Comment: I think that is out of the scope of the question, but anyway IntentResult, as you can see here http://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentResult.html is what you receive when you scan a barcode. You can getRawBytes() to get the information

Comment: You're welcome, please if the answer helped you, mark it as resolved. So everybody can benefit of it.